# VSTS: Execute conditional tasks on builds

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task

In VSTS, I have a GIT repo and a build def with 5 tasks in it.
I have added a branch policy on master branch wherein the build will run when a pull-request is created as a part of check-in policy.
I run that same build as a CI build as well when code is merged from feature branch to master branch.

Now I need to make sure the build runs as part of Pull-Request then only top 4 tasks should be executed and when that same build is run as part of CI(trigger) then all the 5 tasks should get executed.

I cannot find any such out-of-the-box option in VSTS to do this. So need help on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the last task (the task you want to run only in CI) add a custom condition:

`and(succeeded(), ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))`

[image]

Now in a Pull Request, the task will not be executed.